# Problem with calling method from another class for use

Tags: java

So I have these two .java files, one that defines a Dice and another that is going to use the Dice.
I need to implement the roll method from the Dice.java file in the Yahtzee.java file but I'm not sure how to go about doing so.

```
public class Dice {
    private int value;
    
    public Dice() {
        value = -1;
    }
    
    public Dice(int j) { 
        value = j;
    }
    
    public void roll() {
        value = RandomNumber.getRandomNumber(1, 6);
        
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
        
}
```

```
public class Yahtzee {

    private Dice[] dice;

    public Yahtzee() {
    
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to fill array with dices, iterate over each dice, roll it and read result. Which step you have problem with? Can we see your attempt?

Comment: `roll method` is implemented in `Dice`, maybe need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor you will want to instantiate the array of Dice (6 for Yahtzee if memory holds).

```
public class Yahtzee {

  private Dice[] dice = new Dice[6];

  public Yahtzee() {
    for (int index = 0 ; index < dice.length ; ++index) {
      dice[index] = new Dice();
    }
  }
}
```

Now a given instance of Yahtzee owns 6 instances of Dice and can invoke public methods on those instances.  So you can add a method that iterates over those Dice and invokes the roll() method on each as follows:

```
public void roll() {
  for (Dice d : dice) {
    d.roll();
  }
}
```

You will need to implement another method (or modify this one) to handle the re-roll of specific Dice.  This example should be enough to get your started however.

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it is this way:

```
public void roll() {
    Random ran = new Random();
    this.value = ran.nextInt(6) + 1;
    System.out.println(this.value);
    
}
```

Don't forget to **import**  *java.util.Random* in your Dice class

Use **this.value** to update the value of current value in all your methods
And in your **Yahtzee class**, add the following.

```
Dice player1 = new Dice();
Dice player2 = new Dice();
    
player1.roll();
player2.roll();
```

This is just a generalized version as I am not sure what you want to achieve and what you are trying to do.

Using array of objects:
You need to create an array of objects
initialize each index with an instance of the class
and invoke the method using . operator

```
Dice [] dice = new Dice[2];
dice[0] = new Dice();
dice[1] = new Dice();
dice[0].roll();
dice[1].roll();
```